# Which one is called when existing an extern function with the same name as an inline function?

Tags: c++

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
void f()
{
    std::cout<<"non-inline"<<std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
inline void f()
{
    cout<<"inline"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

In debug mode, the output is: non-inline. command:g++ [-g] -o main main.cpp test.cpp

In release mode, the output is: inline. command:g++ -O -o main main.cpp test.cpp

Why?

Linux G++ 4.7.3

In C99, an inline definition does not provide an external definition for the function, so we can provide an external definition of the identifier by defining another function in other source file.

Does an inline definition provide an external definition for the function in C++??

Thx！！

Comment: What are "debug mode" and "release mode" here?

Comment: How do you compile your code? Post the complete compilation command.

Comment: For the debug case it probably depends on link order, as a non-inline version of your inline function will have been generated. Bottom line though: don't do this.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I've edited the thread.

Comment: How are you building your program? Right now main.cpp only includes iostream so the only definition of f as far as your main function is concerned is the one in that file.

Comment: Why doesn't the linker emit ODR warning in debug mode? One `inline` specifier is enough to surpress that?

Comment: Violations of the ODR are not required to be diagnosed.  Linkers typically _don't_ diagnose all of them.

Answer (score 6):

Your program has UB (Undefined Behaviour), because it violates ODR (One Definition Rule) by providing two different definitions of `f()`. There is therefore next to no way of reasoning why it behaves one way or the other. In the best tradition of UB, any behaviour is possible (including ordering pizza over the Internet).

**EDIT**

These quotes from the standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2011) prove it's UB:

[basic.def.odr]§3:

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program; no diagnostic required. ... An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used.

[basic.def.odr]§5:

> There can be more than one definition of ... inline function with
>   external linkage ... in a program provided that each definition
>   appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions
>   satisfy the following requirements. Given such an entity named D
>   defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> - each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and
> - ...

[dcl.fct.spec]§4

> An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same definition in every case (3.2). [ *Note:* A call to the inline function may be encountered before its definition appears in the translation unit. *-end note* ] If the definition of a function appears in a translation unit before its first declaration as inline, the program is ill-formed. **If a function with external linkage is declared inline in one translation unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears; no diagnostic is required.** ...

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: I'm not sure if that is UB, because `inline` lets the compile to define multiple definitions of a name in the program, as per the Standard. The doubt is that one of the name is not marked `inline`, so I don't know what the spec says about such thing.

Comment: LOL! But, the f() in test.cpp isn't an inline function.

Comment: @I'mpossible: It's the same function because it has the same qualified name, the same parameters and external linkage in both translation units. Hence this part applies: "If a function with external linkage is declared inline in one translation unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears; no diagnostic is required."

Comment: Angrew: so as per the text from the spec (the bold text), this is **not** UB, right?

Comment: @Nawaz Er? `f()` is declared `inline` in `main.cpp`, but not in `test.cpp`. So it clearly violates the bolded part. Which means it's ill-formed and as such, its behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @Nawaz: Why do you say that? The program violates a rule of the standard which it's explicitly permitted for the implementation not to diagnose and there is no other stated requirement on the implementation.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: The question is C++ forbids reference to inline function by extern declaration of it only unlike common function with external linkage!

Comment: @I'mpossible Yes. That's how C++ defines "`inline`".

Comment: @I'mpossible: I'm afraid that I failed to parse your comment.

Comment: @Angew: So, the inline function seems to have internal linkage rather than external linkage. It can't be called in other source files by extern declaration without definition. There' no way to define a function with 'real' external linkage having the same name with the inline function, right?

Comment: @CharlesBailey How I understood it: "The question is: Unlike for common functions with external linkage, C++ forbids referring to an inline function only by an extern declaration."

Comment: @I'mpossible It still has external linkage - its address will be the same in all translation units. But inline/non-inline is not part of a function's identity, which means you can't have both an inline and a non-inline function of the same name. So, to answer: yes, right.

Comment: @Angew: I'm very very sorry for my crappy English. I'm not a native English speaker. I mean that common function has external linkage, so i can call it across translation unit by declaration only. However, inline func also has external linkage, but i can't call it in other source files through the func declaration only.

Comment: @I'mpossible No need to apologize; your English is not too bad. If a misunderstanding occurs, we just clear it up and move on. And BTW, I'm not a native English speaker either.

Answer (score 6):

Your program violate the [**One definition Rule**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) then it is [*Undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

When you have an *Undefined behaviour*, anything is possible but you have to know that the worst case will come during the most important demo ;)

The standard says:

> **3.2 One definition rule [basic.def.odr]**
>
> 1/ No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type, or template.
>
> **[...]**
>
> 4/ Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program; no diagnostic required. The definition can appear explicitly in the program, it can be found in the standard or a user-defined library, or (when appropriate) it is implicitly defined (see 12.1, 12.4 and 12.8). **An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used.**
>
> 5/ There can be more than one definition of [...] inline function with external linkage (7.1.2) [...] in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given such an entity named D defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> - each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and
> - [...]
>
> If the definitions of D satisfy all these requirements, then the program shall behave as if there were a single definition of D. If the definitions of D do not satisfy these requirements, **then the behavior is undefined.**

And later:

> **7.1.2 Function specifiers [dcl.fct.spec]**
>
> 4/ **An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same definition in every case** (3.2). [ *Note*: A call to the inline function may be encountered before its definition appears in the translation unit. —*endnote*] **If the definition of a function appears in a translation unit before its first declaration as inline, the program is ill-formed.** If a function with external linkage is declared inline in one translation unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears; no diagnostic is required.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is UB, because `inline` lets the compile to define multiple definitions of a name in the program, as per the Standard. The doubt is that one of the name is not marked `inline`, so I don't know what the spec says about such thing.

Comment: @Nawaz The weird thing is that, there is only one definition by translation unit in fact. It seems that the compiler do optimization in "release mode".

Comment: So as per the text from the spec (the bold text), this is **not** UB, right?

Comment: @Nawaz If you look at 3.2./5 (I quoted), an Undefined Behavior when some requirements are not satisfied when redefining an inline function.

Comment: @Nawaz The standard says that it is undefined behavior.  For two reasons: first, for inline functions, all of the definitions must be identical, and second, if a function is declared inline in one translation unit, it must be declared inline in every translation unit.